# Avoid creating multiple relationships for each match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following model, each `User` is linked to several `Comment` node with the `AUTHORED` relationship, each comment has a `flair` property which can be different on each comment. I also has a `Flair` node, and wish to create a new relationship between `User` nodes and `Flair` nodes.

```
+--------+                          +---------+
|        |                          |         |
|  User  +------+ REL:AUTHORED+-----+ Comment |
|        |                          |         |
+--------+                          +---------+
```

So I wrote the following query to try and do that, but it resulted in a relationship from the `User` node for each `Comment` node with the correct flair. I only want a single relationship between those nodes. How do I achieve that?

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:AUTHORED]-(c:Comment),(b:Flair)
WHERE c.flair = 'foo' and b.name = 'foo'
CREATE (a)-[r:VOTES_FOR]->(b)
RETURN type(a,b,r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` to have only a single relationship between those nodes.

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:AUTHORED]-(c:Comment),(b:Flair)
WHERE c.flair = 'foo' and b.name = 'foo'
MERGE (a)-[r:VOTES_FOR]->(b)
RETURN type(a,b,r)
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid creating duplicate relationships, you should use [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) instead of `CREATE`:

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:AUTHORED]->(c:Comment), (b:Flair)
WHERE c.flair = 'foo' AND b.name = 'foo'
MERGE (a)-[r:VOTES_FOR]->(b)
RETURN a, b, r
```

*This query also removed the use of the `TYPE` function, since your query was using it illegally.*

But I should also note you are introducing redundant data into your DB by adding the `VOTES_FOR` relationship. Instead, I would suggest removing the `flair` property from the `Comment` node and replacing it with a relationship between `Comment` and `Flair` nodes. The following query should achieve that (and would also avoid redundantly storing the same info in multiple places). In addition, it processes all flair values (not just "foo"):

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:AUTHORED]->(c:Comment), (f:Flair)
WHERE c.flair = f.name
REMOVE c.flair
MERGE (c)-[:FOR_FLAIR]->(f)
RETURN u, c, f
```

Or, more efficiently, if you don't really need the `User` to be returned:

```
MATCH (c:Comment), (f:Flair)
WHERE c.flair = f.name
REMOVE c.flair
MERGE (c)-[:FOR_FLAIR]->(f)
RETURN c, f
```

With this new data model, you can find all the distinct Flairs that were authored by a user this way:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[:AUTHORED]->()-[:FOR_FLAIR]->(flair)
WHERE user.id = 123
RETURN user, COLLECT(DISTINCT flair) AS flairs
```